# Change browser's background color (Internet Explorer Mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a mobile web application on **Windows Phone**. 
I chose Cordova as my platform for developing a native app using a WebView.

My problem is that when I'm scrolling to the top/bottom of the page and pull it. **Internet Explorer** shows what's behind the page : a **white background**.

Though Internet Explorer has the same behavior when displaying web pages, I would like to know if there is any way (using HTML, CSS or JS) to change this color or simply prevent the browser from showing it.

Comment: Do other apps created using WebView present the same result?

Comment: Yes they all do. And Internet Explorer has exactly the same behavior when displaying web pages.

Comment: Could you wrap your entire page in another element and add `overflow: scroll`? Then the page would be confined to that parent element.

Comment: Actually I can't. This is a project based on a big JS engine that is not mine. I'm trying to find a way to do it just with CSS or some XML in the config.xml Cordova file.